# Swift: is there an "elegant" way to filter a dictionary value (which is an array)?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, filter

here is this simple example:

```
let i: [String: [Int]] = ["a": [1, 3, 6, 10], 
                          "b": [3, 4, 8, 12]]
```

I would like to create a new dictionary, filtering the arrays in order to get only values which are lower than 7. I wrote this:

```
var j: [String: [Int]] {
    var result = [String: [Int]]()
    i.forEach { key, value in
        result[key] = value.filter({ $0 < 7 })
    }
    return result
}
```

I would like to know, however, if there is a simpler and more elegant way to do this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `mapValues` and then `filter` for the actual values

```
let output = i.mapValues { $0.filter { value in value < 7 } }
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about `mapValues`. Thanks a lot!